# How to configure old Windows clients to use NTLMv2 when connecting to a Windows 7 network share?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, network-shares, ntlm

So we have a shared folder on a Win7 machine which can be accessed from only Vista or later, but apparently reject older clients with error 58.

The reason is that Win7 forces NTLMv2 protocol while older Windowses use NTLM or LM only.

Most suggestions I've found basically about dumbing down Win7 file server to accept LM and NTLM too.

But LM and NTLM is insecure- **So I'd like to do the opposite**: configure the old clients to use NTLMv2 so it can work with Win7. Is it possible?

Comment: Nope, the old OSs don't support NTLMv2; hence why all instruction you find tells you to reduce Windows 7 functionality.  If you want security, stop using old OSs. :)

Comment: @techie007 But even on XP I can set that "accept NTLMv2 only" preference (because it's available since SP2 AFAIK). So I assume that XP knows NTLMv2, still it cannot connect to the Win7 share.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System error 58 while accessing shares on Windows 7 from XP](http://superuser.com/questions/47382/)