# In Windows 10, How to map network drive as System Account?

Tags: windows-10, network-drive

I need to map a network drive as local system account.

In windows 7, I've used PsExec tool to start a Command Prompt as System and use "net use" command to map the required network drive.
The commands I've used are as follows:

```
psexec -s -i cmd.exe
net use z: \\<ip_addr>\<share_name>
```

In Windows 10, that command doesn't seem to work. System Error 58 is showed up.

How can I map a network drive as System Account in Microsoft newest OS?

Comment: The answers here may apply and help potentially (http://superuser.com/questions/47382/system-error-58-while-accessing-shares-on-windows-7-from-xp). I'm surprised mapping to a network resource with `SYSTEM` works to authenticate to the shared resource but I've never done it that way or tested using the `SYSTEM` account. You might read this over too even though the error isn't exactly the same but you may find it helpful (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2686098).

Answer (score 1):

Just came across the same problem trying to map a network drive on Windows 10 from a samba server.

Specifying a valid (samba) user in the net use command solved this:

```
net use z: \\server\share /user:username password
```